# Delete Square in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have encountered this problem. The first row is highlighters. How can I solve it.
Here is the code :

```vb
Sub DeleteSquare()
    If (Selection.Name <> "Square") Then
        MsgBox ("Not a Square!")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If (MsgBox("Are you sure?", vbYesNo, "Confirmation") = vbYes) Then
        Selection.DeletenumSquares = numSquares - 1
        Range("NoOfSquares").Value = numSquares
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What's up with all the extra parentheses?

Comment: `Range.Name` only exists if the range has been explicitly named. `Selection` is a range, but if the range it currently references has not been explicitly named, a run-time error occurs when attempting to inspect the name. Your approach should be reconsidered unless you can ensure that every cell has been named which is unlikely in the extreme.